# Use search command of search bar on list view with mvvm pattern

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, data-binding, xamarin.forms

I'm a beginner on xamarin mvvm patter. Currently I'm trying to create a search bar that searches the word from a list of names. I tried to write some codes on comman function on my view model and bind it on the `SearchCommand` of search bar on view. But it didn't work. Here's my code

```
namespace HelloWorld.ViewModel
{

    public class CustViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private custmodel _custmodel;


        public custmodel custmodel
        {
            get { return _custmodel; }
            set
            {
                _custmodel = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string _message;
        public string message
        {
            get { return _message; }
            set
            {
                _message = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private ObservableCollection<string> _list;
        public ObservableCollection<string> Items
        {
            get
            {
        return _list;
            }
            set
            {
                _list = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public Command SaveCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(() =>
                {
                    message = "Your task : " + custmodel.name + ", " + custmodel.surname + " was successfully saved!";
                });
            }
        }

        private string _bar;

        public string Bar
        {
            get { return _bar; }
            set { _bar = value;
        }
    }

    public Command SearchCommand
{
    get
    {
            return new Command(() =>
            {
                string keyword = _bar;
                IEnumerable<String> searchresult = _list.Where(name => name.Contains(keyword));
                _list = new ObservableCollection<string>(searchresult);
                NotifyPropertyChanged();
            }
                );


    }
}

public CustViewModel()
{

    custmodel = new custmodel
    {
        name = "Aasish",
        surname = "Gurung",
        email = "iamaaceez@yahoo.com"
    };
    _list = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    _list.Add("Saurab");
    _list.Add("Basanta");
    _list.Add("Abhishek");
    _list.Add("Surace");
    _list.Add("Amir");

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;


    //public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }

    }
}
```

Here is my xaml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         x:Class="HelloWorld.Styling"
         BackgroundColor="AntiqueWhite" Title="Hello"
         xmlns:converters="clr-namespace:HelloWorld.Converters; assembly=HelloWorld">

<StackLayout>
    <SearchBar x:Name="MainSearchBar" Text="{Binding Bar}"
               SearchCommand="{Binding SearchCommand}"/>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
</StackLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

First, make sure you are setting your `ContentPage`'s `BindingContext` to your `CustViewModel`.

Also, you should stop assigning and adding things to `_list` and instead assign and add things to your public `Items` property. `Items` is the one that will trigger the `NotifyPropertyChanged()` method when it has been assigned to.

So change your `SearchCommand` to this:

```
return new Command(() => {
    string keyword = _bar;
    IEnumerable<String> searchresult = _list.Where(name => name.Contains(keyword));

    Items = new ObservableCollection<string>(searchresult);

    //NotifyPropertyChanged(); //There is no reason to trigger NotifyPropertyChanged on this command each time the getter is run, I would image that this could cause an infinite loop
});
```

Comment: Thanks, appreciate your help. I want to return the list view with the full list if the text on the search bar is empty. How do I do it?

Comment: @AasishGrg It is best to ask a new question instead of asking multiple in the same post, but you would have to keep a separate list with all of the items in it or make a new call to your data API, if there is one, and ask for the full list.